# Youtube api does not find removed/duplicate video's anymore

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Since a few days the youtube api does not give response when I search on video id with at url

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={VIDEO_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

when I upload a video via api, and it gets removed by youtube because it is duplicated or some other reason, I don't see the status anymore via api. Is this a new or is it a bug? I don't see any changes in api. The video is also not in playlist when I check with the playlistitem api.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better directed at the Google Customer Service.

Comment: When you want to get support for API they redirect you to stack overflow. I think there are no other ways? Google does monitor the tags I used. so I hope they will answer my question.

Comment: If your code works and has worked  and still implements the API correctly there is nothing we can do here. SO is meant to solve programming problems not support issues that are related to the SLA or contracts of individual customers. I admit that the distinction can be a bit hard to make, specially if Google hasn't made that clear on their site.